# The notification message saying that one of my answers have been migrated keeps to be shown

Tags: support, notifications

I keep getting a message about an answer of mine that have been migrated: All the times I go to Stack Overflow, the message appears again, even if I click on the closing button. I also tried clicking on the links reported in the message but it didn't help.

How do I stop the message from appearing again?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I always used the same browser and the same computer, to visit Stack Overflow, and any other SE sites.